# How can I navigate the DOM for the contents of an XML object

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an XML file, and I would like to extract the contents of a tag called `issueId`. I have tried

```
alert(myXML.getElementsByTagName("issueId")[0]);
```

and I get a box saying `[object element]`
I also tried

I however cannot extract the data "12345" itself! I have tried

```
alert(myXML.getElementsByTagName("issueId")[0].nodeValue);
```

and I get "null". How can I just get the contents of this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `myXML.getElementsByTagName("issueId")[0].textContent`